# WebTestClient Authenticated Request

Tags: spring-boot, spring-security, jwt, spring-webflux

I'm trying to test my reactive(WebFlux) controller. Authenticated user makes request and I create some resource and current user is its owner(I need to know, who made this request, so simple @WithMockUser doesn't work). I use JWT authentication.

And I can't write proper test for that. In case of simple Spring MVC, there is

```
mockMvc.perform(...).with(user("username").roles("USER"))..
```

But I can't find anything similar for WebFlux. I tried to mutate webTestClient like this:

```
webTestClient.mutateWith(mockUser(...))
webTestClient.mutateWith(mockAuthentication(...))
```

Unfortunately, it doesn't work.

Any help is appreciated! Thanks in advance.

Comment: What about SecurityMockServerConfigurers.JwtMutator? You can mock the whole Jwt token.